# How can I open the slide menu without using the storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, xib

I want to open the slide menu using xib instead of using the storyboard.

First, the design of the slide menu for the slide menu is too difficult.
Can you tell me who owns a design sample for the slide menu?

Secondly, my file structure is linked to `BaseViewController.swift` and `MainViewController.swift`, so the screen is centered around `MainViewController.swift`

> MainViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
class MainViewController: BaseViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)            
        initialize()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        slideMenu()         <----- here make slide menu`s button            
    }
}
```

> BaseViewController.swift

```
  import UIKit
  class BaseViewController: UIViewController {...}
```

but The problem is this.
I need to make it without using the slide menu library.
Other menus change the screen via the code below when the button is pressed.

> MainViewController.swift

```
@IBAction func openMenu(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let open:MenuViewController = MenuViewController()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(open, animated: true)
}
```

If you follow the slide menu, you will find that, in the slide menu, you can divide the slide into the slide menu, and then empty the empty space to the blank view.

And when the screen changes, it's basically left to the left.
But I just want to get the slide menu right from left to right. 
Swift is the first. Please help me!!

In addition, the slide menu buttons are added to the code instead of xib.

> MainViewController.swift

```
func SlideMenu() {

    let slideBtn: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40))
    slideBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "btn_slide.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    slideBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MainViewController.onSlideMenu(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    btn.isExclusiveTouch = true
    let leftSlideButton:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: slideBtn)
    self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(leftSlideButton, animated: true)

}
```

Comment: slide menu you mean hamburger menu?

Comment: @TusharSharma yes. right